# xcolor gives me 101 errors

Tags: tables, errors, color

I wanted to use the `xcolor` package to get the possibility of creating different shades of certain colors, in this case `black!90`.
After including `xcolor` in my document I suddenly get 101 errors. I have found out so far that it only happens when I have a `tabular` environment in the document. When removing the `[table]` part before the `{xcolor}` I only get 45 errors. Does anyone know why this happens? Did I do something wrong? Can I use a different package for the same effect?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the number of errors is totally unimportant (many errors after the first will be spurious) but you should show the _full text_ from the log file of the first error if you want help with that,

Comment: you are missing the mandatory argument from `tabular` `\begin{tabular}{cccc}`

Comment: Welcome! What DC said ^^.

Comment: In the binary digit system it would be only 5 errors ;-) (off-topic, naughty comment)

Answer (score 5):

It is usually best to ignore all errors after the first (or stop the run after the first error) very often after recovering from an error TeX is in an inconsistent or unexpected state and so just generates more spurious errors.

The error in your document is

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\end): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \end
        {tabular}
?
```

Which tells you that the error is from processing defined in the array package so it is the tabular and that it has read the `\end` token on line 9 which is not a legal `pream-token` (that is a table column specifier).

TeX saw your document as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{\end}
{tabular}
\end{document}
```

as `\begin{tabular}` always reads one argument which should be something like `{ccc}` for three centred columns.